# What does char* (int) mean in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following line of code in one of the projects I am working on:

```
char* i2txt(int);
```

And I don't exactly understand what it does?
With my half-knowledge I was trying to make it work with floats, so I changed the int to a float, but that gives me an error.

```
char* i2txt(int);
/*vs*/
char* i2txt(float);
```

Error Message :

> ```
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "char * __cdecl i2txt(float)" (?i2txt@@YAPADM@Z) referenced in function "public: char * __thiscall DapChannel::getDurationTxt(void)" (?getDurationTxt@DapChannel@@QAEPADXZ)  PhotoZ  DapChannel.obj  1
> ```

Comment: `char* i2txt(int);` is a **function declaration**. It says that somewhere else there is a definition of a function named `i2txt` that takes an argument of type `int` and returns a `char*`. Similarly for `char* i2txt(float);`, except that the argument type is `float`. There's nothing wrong with those two declarations, so you'll have to expand on "gives me an error". Unless, of course, you're compiling this as C code, in which case you can't have to functions with the same name.

Comment: Just fyi: I assume some people downvoted this because you didn't provide the error message, which would have been helpful. Other than that it's a completely valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `char* i2txt(int);` is forward-declaring a function `i2txt` that takes an `int` as input, and returns a `char*`.

#### What is forward-declaration?

If you have a function used before it's declared, that results in an error:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    foo(); // Error: foo not defined
} 
void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!"; 
}
```

**Forward-declaration** basically states "This function isn't defined yet, but I promise I'll define it eventually. In the above case, it'd look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(); // Forward declaration

int main() {
    foo(); // Now we can use it
}

void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
}
```

#### Why do you get an error when you change it to `i2txt(float);`?

This results in an error because suddenly, there's no `i2txt(int)` function to call. Because `int`s can be implicitly converted to `float`, the compiler still allows other functions to call `i2txt(float)`, but no definition for `i2txt(float)` is ever provided, so there's a linker error:

```
#include <iostream>
char* i2txt(float);

int main() {
    std::cout << i2txt(10); // Tries calling i2txt(float)
}

// This provides a definition for i2txt(int), but the linker is still missing a definition for i2txt(float)
char* i2txt(int) {
    // ... stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This declares a function accepting an integer and returning a char pointer.

I'm guessing the error you got after changing it was a linker error, telling you that it doesn't find a definition for `i2txt` with a float parameter. That's because the definition of this function, which is provided elsewhere, accepts an integer parameter not a float.

Answer (score 3):

It declares a function which takes an int (by value), and returns a point to char.  Given the name (integer to text), the pointer is almost certainly to a null terminated sequence of characters which are the text version of the number.  The pointer will either be to a static variable in the function (which means it is not thread safe, and the resulting text must be copied if you want to save it), or to a dynamically allocated array (in which case it must be freed).  A function returning a `std::string` would be much better.

Comment: Given OP's confusion, it's likely that they weren't the one to write this function, and that it appears in a library they're using.

Answer (score 3):

Its just a function declaration that take and `int` argument and return `char*` :

```
// Declaration :
char* i2txt(int);

// Definition :
char* i2txt(int n)
{
    // do something
}
```

But the occurred `error` is because there's an implementation of `i2txt` function that take an `int` argument and when you trying to change the declaration (especially if the implementation defined in an static library) it give you the linker `error` like the bellow :

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char * __cdecl a(float)" (?a@@YAPADM@Z) referenced in...

In the normal state, if you call `i2txt` with a `float` value, it may cast float number to int, BUT if you trying to change the declaration of `i2txt` the link error will be occur (***If the definition is in a static library***).